# limit inferior of a measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

I'm try to do the exercise 2.E to the Elements of integration and Lebergue measure; Bartle
Let $\left(A_n\right)$ be a sequence of subsets of a set $\textbf{X}$. If B consists of all $x \in X$ which belong to all but a finite number of the sets $( A_n)$, show that
$B=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}{\left[\bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty}A_n\right]}$

I have done the following

Let $x \in \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}{\left[\bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty}A_n\right]}$, so exist $m_0$ such that $x \in \bigcap_{n=m_0}^{\infty}A_n$, then $x\in A_n$ for all $n\geq m_0$

I don't know how continue

Comment: $\ldots$ for all $n \geq m_{0},$ so $x$ is excluded **at most** from $A_1,\,A_2,\,\ldots,\,A_{m_0 - 1},$ and hence $x$ belongs to all but finitely many of the sets. (The reason for "at most" is that there may be fewer sets that $x$ doesn't belong to. For example, if all the sets are the same, then $x$ would not be excluded from any of them.) For the other direction, pick $m_0$ to be a positive integer greater than the index of any of the sets that $x$ does not belong to, and use $m_0$ in the same manner that it was used earlier.